# How can i make 3dObjects infront gui texture in unity3d

Tags: c#, user-interface, camera, unity-game-engine

I created gui texture by writing hard code in gui function in script.

Main camera depth is -1

```
void OnGUI() {  
   GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(screenResolution.x - 25 * guiDiff, screenResolution.y  - 310 * guiDiff, 15 * guiDiff, 300  * guiDiff), fullProgressBar);    
}
```

How can I make 3D objects in front of it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself, but you can try to use two cameras.

The first camera should have the `GUILayer` component with a *lower* draw order (depth).

The second camera should have no `GUILayer` component and set its clear flag to "Depth only" with a *higher* draw order (depth).

Comment: How i give layer for gui button?

Answer (score 0):

you can put a plane in front of the camera, then put the texture on the plane, and then put the 3d objects in front of the plane

check [this](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/change-3d-object-button-imagetarget-example-unity3d) out, that might be what you need

Comment: I have to create gui button

Comment: i put a link that might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Have two cameras on your scene.

Camera1 : GUI Layer with depth = 1.

Camera2 : **No GUI Layer with depth 2** for 3D objects above GUI.

Also for your convenience, **create a layer with a name 3DGUI** and **set layer mask** of all 3D objects that you want to show above GUI.

Also **set culling mask of Camera2** to only 3DGUI.

You are done with the solution.